# Creating a table using PDO - not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know there are a few threads on this, but I've gone through them and haven't yet found a solution.

The problem I'm having is that when I execute my code to create a table using PHP's PDO object, nothing happens. I don't get an error, but I don't get a table either.

Here is my code:

```
    $pdo = new pdo('mysql:localhost;ijdb','root','');
try {  
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE joke 
    (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            joketext TEXT,
            jokedate DATE NOT NULL
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB'; 
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO joke values
    (
        (1,"jokes","2014-04-22")
    )';
    $pdo->exec($sql);
 } 
catch (PDOException $e) {  $output = 'Error creating joke table: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit(); }
```

As I said, nothing happens at all, the table isn't created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And if this is a duplicate post, please point me in the right direction and I'll remove this post.

Comment: `$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Your connect string is all wrong. It should look like `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ijdb'`

Comment: You need to be sure you have turned on PHP's error reporting, as the initial `new PDO` would throw an exception _before_ your try/catch.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _always_ when developing code.  Then enable all exceptions on the PDO object as @GhostGambler suggested.

Comment: ^^In general, no output from PHP when output is otherwise expected (even an error message) is a strong indicator of a fatal error that wasn't reported.

Comment: And put the `new PDO` *inside* the try/catch block, as shown in examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for the quick feedback. I've inserted the error exception code and moved the new PDO code into the Try statement, but I'm still getting neither errors nor a table. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make this work, do the following:

***Sidenote:*** This will create a new data entry of the same `jokes` and `2014-04-22`.

If you don't want to keep adding the same, set a new query along with a seperate script using
[**(PDO with) prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). and/or set your columns to be `UNIQUE`.

Nota: The `1` should be omitted from the `INSERT`, since your `id` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
try {

 $pdo = new pdo('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db', 'username', 'password_if_any');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS joke
    (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            joketext TEXT,
            jokedate DATE NOT NULL

                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    INSERT INTO joke (joketext, jokedate) values ('jokes','2014-04-22')";

    $pdo->exec($sql);

 } 
catch (PDOException $e) {  

$output = 'Error creating joke table: ' . $e->getMessage();

echo $output;
exit(); 
}
```